# nltk measure the accuracy of the new features

Tags: prediction, nltk

I have been playing around the NLTK algorithm for some data prediction.

Starting from this [gib](https://github.com/EdmundMartin/nltk_classify), I started my understanding process. However, there are some bits that don't make sense.

If I have a set of 100 features, all classified, what's the sense to split them, take 10% and build the training set on that alone?
I thought the training set should have included all the list, and accuracy is measured against the new keywords being tested against?

Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have a classified testing set - which allows to measure a performance score, then it is useful to use part of your training data as a validation set, meaning that you test the performance of your model on it (because you have the true labels/values).

The percentage of the split is arbitrary and depends on the degrees of freedom you have (number of individuals vs number of variables) - 0.1 to 0.25 is a common choice.

Comment: Hi, I have my trained test set already, and the example n the git calculates the accuracy by splitting the training set in two parts. However, if I change the code to use the full data set (300 words) and later classify the keyword and check its accuracy I always get 100%, which I love but sounds strange because no matter which sentence I test, the accuracy is always that hgh. Any idea?